# Create tasklets at runtime

Tags: python, python-stackless, tasklet

Just starting with Stackless Python. I'm trying to create some tasklets at run time, that is, after calling `stackless.run()`. I thought this function wouldn't block the main thread, so I would be able to create new tasklets when necessary. So I decided to make a tasklet-creator function that run in a tasklet. This is what I have:

```
import stackless

from time import sleep

def say_hello(s):
    while True:
        print("Hello, %s!" % s)
        sleep(5)

def creator():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        t = stackless.tasklet(say_hello)(str(i))
        t.insert()
        sleep(5)

stackless.tasklet(creator)()
stackless.run()
```

This code should create a new tasklet every 5 seconds, and each one should print "Hello, {number of tasklet}!" infinitely (every 5 seconds, too). The expected output is:

```
Hello, 1!
Hello, 1!
Hello, 2!
Hello, 1!
Hello, 2!
Hello, 3!
Hello, 1!
Hello, 2!
Hello, 3!
Hello, 4!
...
```

But when running the code there's no output.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but I think you need to call `stackless.schedule()` after the t.insert() before sleeping in creator(). I think creator is not giving control back. Same for say_hello.